# How to replace each match with incrementing counter?

Tags: substitute

I want to search and replace each occurrence of a certain pattern with a decimal number which begins at `1` and increments by one for each match.

I can find similarly worded questions that turn out not to be about incrementing a counter but modifying each match by a fixed amount. Other similar questions are about inserting line numbers rather than an incrementing counter.

Example, before:

```
#1
#1.25
#1.5
#2
```

After:

```
#1
#2
#3
#4
```

My real data has a lot more text all around the stuff I want to re-number.

Comment: if you have `perldo`, you can use `:%perldo s/#\K\d+(\.\d+)?/++$i/ge`

Comment: @Sundeep: i should've mentioned I'm on vanilla Windows 10, sorry!

Answer (score 23):

```
 :let @a=1 | %s/search/\='replace'.(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```

But beware, it will overwrite your register `a`.
I think it is a little bit more straight forward than luc's answer, but maybe his is faster. If this solution is somehow worse than his, I would love to hear any feedback why his answer is better. Any feedback to improve the answer will be highly appreciated!

(It is also based on a SO answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539251/how-to-replace-finding-words-with-the-different-in-each-occurrence-in-vi-vim-edi/43539546#43539546)

Comment: I don't see how `@a+setreg('a',@a+1)` is shorter than `len(add(t,1))`. Otherwise, this is a nice other dirty trick :). I haven't though of this one. Regarding the use of a dictionary mutating function in the replacement text, of `:s` and `substitute()`, I have noted this is much faster that explicit loops -- hence the [implementation of my list functions in lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/commit/1173c856e2a415254f986f16437b96b847b9de73). I guess your solution will be on par with mine, may be a little faster, I don't know.

Comment: Regarding preferences, I prefer my solution for a single reason: it leaves `@a` unmodified. In scripts, this is important IMO. While in interactive mode, as a end-user, I'll know which register I can use. Messing with a register is less important. In my solution, in interactive mode, a global variable is messed with; in a script it'd be a local variable.

Comment: @LucHermitte Sorry, my solution is indeed not shorter than yours, I should read it better before writing such a statement. I have removed the said statement from my answer and would like to apologize! Thank you for your interesting feedback, I appreciate it.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Because of the regex, it's easy to think there is a lot to type. Also, I voluntarily admit my solution is convoluted. You're welcomed for the feedback. :)

Comment: Yeah changing a register in a script is dangerous, but I found this dirty trick quite usefull for solving this kind of problems interactivly. So for a clean solution, i would probably go for yours. However to do it quick and dirty, the regsiter solution would also work with `+3` or i think even `-1`. (I know it is possible with yours too, but it would need more thinking/coding at the end ;-) )

Comment: Indeed you're rigth. Most of the time I extract another information that I store in the last position of the array, which is what (the last element) I insert in the end. For instance, for a `+3`, I could write something like `\=add(thelist, 3 + get(thelist, -1, 0))[-1]`.

Comment: How can I make `'replace'` a capture group reference (e.g., `\1`)?

Comment: @Geremia I figured out I need to use `submatch(1)`, instead of `\1`.

Answer (score 18):

You need substitution with a state. I remember having provided a (/several?) [complete solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim) for this kind of problems on SO.

Here is another way to proceed (1). 
Now, I'll proceed into 2 steps:

- a dummy list variable I need for the dirty and convoluted trick I'll employ
- a substitution where I insert the len of this dummy array I'm filling on each matching occurrence.

Which gives:

```
:let t=[]
:%s/#\zs\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\=\ze/\=len(add(t,1))/g
```

If you're not used to vim regexes, I use `:h /\zs` and `\ze` to specify which sub-pattern I'm matching, then I match a series of digits possibly followed by a dot and other digits. This is not perfect for any floating point number, but this is enough here.

Note: You'll have to wrap it up in a couple function + command for a simple interface. Again, there are examples on SO/vim ([here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3028), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25665554/15934))
Nowadays I know enough of vim to not care about wrapping this trick into a command. Indeed I'll be able to write this command on the first try, while I'll take several minutes to remember the name of the command.

---

(1) The objective is to be able to maintain a state in-between substitutions, and to replace the current occurrence with something that depends on the current state.

Thanks to [`:s\=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3as%5c%3d) we are able to insert something resulting from a computation.

Remains the problem of the state. Either we define a function that's managing an external state, or we update ourselves an external state. In C (and related languages), we could have used something like `length++` or `length+=1`. Unfortunately, in vim scripts, `+=` cannot be used out of the box. It needs to be used either with `:set` or with `:let`. This means that `:let length+=1` increments a number, but doesn't return anything. We cannot write `:s/pattern/\=(length+=1)`. We need something else.

We need mutating functions. i.e. functions that mutates their inputs. We have `setreg()`, `map()`, `add()` and probably more. Let's start with them.

- [`setreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setreg%28%29) mutates a register. Perfect. We can write `setreg('a',@a+1)` as in @Doktor OSwaldo's solution. And yet, this is not enough. `setreg()` is more of a procedure than a function (for those among us who know Pascal, Ada...). This means it doesn't return anything. Actually, it does return something. Nominal exit (i.e. *non-exceptionnal* exits) always return something. By default, [when we forgot to return something, 0 is returned](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Areturn) -- it also applies with built-in functions. That's why in his solution the replacement expression is actually `\=@a+setreg(...)`. Tricky, isn't it?
- [`map()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#map%28%29) could also be used. If we start from a list with a single 0 (`:let single_length=[0]`), we could increment it thanks to `map(single_length, 'v:val + 1')`. Then we need to return the new length. Unlike `setreg()`, `map()` returns its mutated input.  That's perfect, the length is stored at the first (and unique, and thus last as well) position of the list. The replacement expression could be `\=map(...)[0]`.
- [`add()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#add%28%29) is the one I often use out of habit (I've just though about `map()` actually, and I haven't benched their respective performances yet). The idea with `add()` is to use a list as the current state, and to append something at the end before each substitution. I often store the new value at the end of the list, and use it for the replacement. As `add()` also returns its mutated input list, we can use: `\=add(state, Func(state[-1], submatch(0)))[-1]`. In OP's case, we only need to remember how many matches have been detected so far. Returning the length of this state list is enough. Hence my `\=len(add(state, whatever))`.

Comment: I think I understand this one, but why the trick with the array and it's length compared to adding one to a variable?

Comment: This is because `\=` expects an expression, and because unlike C, `i+=1` isn't something that do increment *and* do return an expression. This means that behind `\=` I need something that can modify a counter and that returns an expression (equal to that counter). So far, the only things I've found are the list (and dictionary) manipulation functions. @Doktor OSwaldo has used another mutating function (`setreg()`). the difference is that `setreg()` never returns anything, which means it always returns the number `0`.

Comment: Wow, interesting! Both your trick and his are so magical that I think your answers would benefit from explaining them in your answers. I would assume only the most fluent vimscripters would know such unintuitive idioms.

Comment: @hippietrail. Explanations added.Let me know if you need more specific precisions.

Answer (score 8):

I found a similar but different question I asked a couple of years ago and managed to change one of its answers without fully understanding what I was doing and it's been working great:

```
:let i = 1 | g/#\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\=/s//\=printf("#%d", i)/ | let i = i+1
```

Specifically I don't understand why mine doesn't use `%` or why I just use a plain variable that the other answers avoid for some reason.

Comment: that is also a possiblity. I think the main disadvantage here is, that you use one substitute command per match. So it is probably slower. The reason why we don't use a plain variable, is, that it will not be updated in a normal `s//g` statement. Anyway it is an interesting solution. Maybe @LucHermitte can tell you more about pros and cons, since my knowledge about vimscript is quite limited compared with his.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo. I guess this solution has been working for a longer time -- without `printf()` though -- as Lists were introduced in Vim 7. But I must admit I wouldn't have expected (/didn't remember?) the `<bar>` to belong to the scope of `:global` -- IOW, the scenario I'd have expected was to apply the `:sub` on the matching lines, then increment `i` once at the very end. I expect this solution to be slightly slower. But does it really matter? The important thing is how easily we're able to come over with a working solution from memory + trial & error. For instance, Vimgolfers prefer macros.

Comment: @LucHermitte yeah i ecpexted the same, and no the speed doesn't matter. I think it is a good answer, and I again learned something from it. Maybe the `g/s//` scope behaviour allowes for other dirty tricks. So thank you both for the interesting answers and discussion, I do not often learn that much from giving an answer =).

Answer (score 7):

There are already [three](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12871/343) [great](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12869/343) [answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12868/343) on this page, but, as [Luc Hermitte suggested in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/how-to-replace-each-match-with-incrementing-counter#comment22139_12871), if you're doing this off-the-cuff, the important thing is how quickly and easily you can alight upon a working solution.

As such, this is a problem that I wouldn't actually use `:substitute` for at all: it's one that can easily be solved using regular normal mode commands and a recursive macro:

1. *(If necessary)* First, turn off `'wrapscan'`. The regular expression we're going to use will match the desired result text as well as the initial text, so with `'wrapscan'` on, the macro would otherwise continue playing back forever. (Or until you realise what's happening and press `<C-C>`.):

   ```
   :set nowrapscan
   ```
2. Set up your search term (using the same base regular expression already mentioned in the existing answers):

   ```
   /#\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?<CR>
   ```
3. *(If necessary)* Jump back to the first match by pressing `N` as many times as required,
4. *(If necessary)* Change the first match into the desired text:

   ```
   cE#1<Esc>
   ```
5. Clear out the `"q` register and start recording a macro:

   ```
   qqqqq
   ```
6. Yank the current counter:

   ```
   yiW
   ```
7. Jump to the next match:

   ```
   n
   ```
8. Replace the current counter with the one we just yanked:

   ```
   vEp
   ```
9. Increment the counter:

   ```
   <C-A>
   ```
10. Play macro `q`. Register `"q` is still empty because we cleared it in step 5, so nothing happens at this point:

    ```
    @q
    ```
11. Stop recording the macro:

    ```
    q
    ```
12. Play the new macro, and watch!

    ```
    @q
    ```

As with all macros, this looks like a lot of steps when explained as I have done above, but note that actually typing these in is *very* quick for me: apart from the recursive-macro-recording-boilerplate they're all just the regular editing commands I'm performing all the time during editing. The only step where I had to do anything even *approaching* thinking was step 2, where I wrote the regular expression to perform the search.

Formatted as two command-line mode commands and a series of keystrokes, the speed of this type of solution becomes more clear: I can conjure up the following pretty much as fast as I can type it<sup>1</sup>:

```
:set nowrapscan
/#\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?
cE#1<Esc>qqqqqyiWnvEp<C-A>@qq@q
```

I probably could have come up with the other solutions on this page with a bit of thought and some referencing of the documentation<sup>2</sup>, but, once you understand how macros work, they really are easy to churn out at whatever speed you usually edit.

<sub>1: There *are* situations where macros require more thought, but I find they don't come up much in practice. And generally the situations where they occur are ones where a macro is the *only* practical solution.</sub>

<sub>2: Not to imply that the other answerers couldn't have come up with their solutions similarly easily: they just require skills/knowledge that I personally don't have so easily at my fingertips. But *all* Vim users know how to use regular editing commands!</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Just adding '#' at the end plus a counter 'c'

```
:let c=0 | g/^#\d\+.*/ let c+=1 | s//\='#' . c
```

The global part `g/^#\d\+.*/ let c+=1` allow us to increment
the counter only in the lines that have a pattern

Comment: Isnt that covered in hippietrails answer?

Comment: In this case, I think I have figured out a shorter way of doing something similar, maybe a comment would be better.