# Find and replace with incrementing numbers

Tags: search, replace

I have several lines that look like the following:

```
"Timestamp": 200,
"Timestamp": 1200,
"Timestamp": 3100,
```

I want to replace all the numbers, starting at 10 and incrementing by 10's so it looks like this:

```
"Timestamp": 10,
"Timestamp": 20,
"Timestamp": 30,
```

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12867/10604, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4951533/4400820, etc. (search "vim substitute increment")

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if you are looking for pure `:%s///` solution or not.

I would approach this with `10` + `g` + `<C-a>`:

1. replace all numbers with `0`: `:%s/\d\+,/0,`
2. select all zeroes and increment them by 10: `10g<C-a>`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Vimscript variable and increment it after each substitution. By using the `:g` command with a pattern, you can follow it with both a `:s` to replace the number (using `\=` in the replacement part to use the Vimscript variable) and also a `:let` command to increment the variable.

```
:let a = 10 | g/^"Timestamp": \zs\d\+\ze,$/ s//\=a/ | let a += 10
```

See:

- `:help :bar` (the bar `|` is used as a command separator in Vimscript.)
- `:help :let` to assign and increment a Vimscript variable.
- `:help :g` (the `:global` command executes another Ex command for each matching line.)
- `:help /\zs` and `:help /\ze`: these markers mark the start and end of the match in a regular expression.
- `:help :s` for the substitute. The empty pattern `//` makes it reuse the same pattern from the `:g` command.
- `:help sub-replace-expression` for using `\=` in a substitution replacement to evaluate a Vimscript expression.

Comment: How would you reverse this expression correctly? For example, what if the number was to the left of the colon, like 0 : "Timestamp" ? 

Would this work? 

 :let a = 10 | g/ : \zs\d\+\ze,$/ s//\=a/  : "Timestamp" | let a += 10

Comment: @AdjunctProfessorFalcon You can use e.g. `/\d\+\ze\s*: "Timestamp"/` as the pattern in that case, so `g/\d\+\ze\s*: "Timestamp"/ s//\=a/` for the middle part of the expression. You don't need to change the `:s` command at all, only the pattern given to `:g` and make sure you still use `\ze` (and `\zs` if appropriate) to isolate the number you want to replace.

Answer (score 3):

One more way, using a macro:

First set the unmamed register to contain zero:

```
:let @n=0
```

Then record into a register of your choice (but not the 'n' register, since
we're using that above! e.g. `qa` to use the 'a' register) the following macro
(where `^A` is pressing 'ctrl'+'a'):

```
0Wdt,"nP10^A"nyiwj
```

The way it works is as follows:

- `0W`  moves to the start of the line, then jumps to the number
- `dt,` deletes the existing number
- `"nP` pastes the contents of the 'n' register (which we initally set to
  zero)
- `10^A` increment the number we just pasted by 10
- `"nyiw` replace the contents of the 'n' register by the incremented number
- `j` move down to the next line

Now you can run apply the macro to all the remaining lines:

```
:2,$norm @a
```