# Add incrementing numbers to lines

Tags: substitute, list

How do I numbers starting from 1 to a range of lines (thereby creating an ordered list)? For example, the following

```
foo
bar
baz
```

would turn into

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 baz
```

I know to use the visual block to insert `0`  to each line and then `gvg<c-a>` to get the desired result, but somehow I found that inelegant (though it is looking better and better as I write this). Is there a better method, presumably one that accomplishes this in one step? Perhaps something with `:'<,'>s/^/`?

PS I know from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253041/1493867) that I could use `:'<,'>s/^/\=(line('.')-line("'<")+1)/`, but that would be even clunkier (which is why my solution doesn't seem so bad now).

Comment: This has some related info/links: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/35186/10604

Comment: `g<C-A>` in Visual mode was what I was going to suggest when I read the top of your question... So, yeah, I think that's pretty much the most straightforward way.

Comment: I was thinking of a function `Inc()` that increments a variable and returns its previous value, so you could use `\=Inc()` on the replacement side. I thought of the advantage of that approach (over `g<C-A>` in Visual mode) and realized it could be used to number non-contiguous lines, if used with `:g`. Then I looked at Ben's linked question, and noticed I answered with something to that same effect, but without the need of a helper, just using the `| let a += 1` be part of what `:g` executes... So, in effect, that answer is what I'd suggest here.

Comment: While the questions are not exactly the same, I think the answers for that one fit pretty much perfectly for this question. I'd be willing to mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on linux, you could filter the text through the external command `nl`
to 'number the lines of files' with the `--number-width=1` argument to ensure
no leading whitespace:

```
:%!nl -w1
```

This outputs:

```
1   foo
2   bar
3   baz
.
.
.
10  more
11  things
```

Using the`%` sign means do the command for 'all lines in the buffer'. But you
could also do `20,30!nl -w1` to do it only for lines 20-30, or you can visually
select the region you care about, hit colon, and it will only apply to the
selected lines - the `:'<,'>` is actually the lines between the two marks `'<`
and `'>`. This means you can use *any* two marks: `:'a,'b!nl -wq`.

You can also specify the range with patterns like: `:/pattern1/,/pattern2/!nl -w1`

See `:help cmdline-ranges` for all the possibilities.

Comment: I'm not on Linux, but wouldn't that work on every line in the file instead of the selection? I want the numbers on only certain lines.

Comment: @bongbang Yes you're right about the `%` sign, but you can use a custom range as detailed in the update to the answer.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252766/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-range-of-lines-in-vim#252777) and its comments.