# How do I append every single occurance of a phrase with that phrase plus an incremental number?

Tags: key-bindings, vscode

I am using the Vim extension in VSCode.

I want to append every occurrence of a phrase, for example:

```
breadCrumbLabel
```

In my codebase with the instance number. The first occurrence would have to be:

```
breadCrumbLabel 1
```

the second would be:

```
breadCrumbLabel 2
```

and so on.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace each match with incrementing counter?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/how-to-replace-each-match-with-incrementing-counter) There's several different techniques there: hopefully _one_ of them works in VSCode.

Comment: Thz common understanding is that rhe VsCode plugin is not in the score of this site (see [what is vi](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37/23502)) but the redirection of romainl could help you partly :-)

Comment: Yes. The Vi(m)-like behavior of the plugin is on-topic, but VSCode-specific parts are not.

Comment: So... we close part of the question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vim, I would use `:grep` or `:vimgrep` to fill the quickfix list (or a location-list variant) and then use the classic

```
:let i = 1
:cdo substitute/$/\=' '..i/ | let i += 1
```

Here I’ve assumed the instances are spread out across files. If they are locally contained, any of the solutions at [How to replace each match with incrementing counter?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/how-to-replace-each-match-with-incrementing-counter) should do.