# How may I create an excmd that has a signature like g, s, v commands? (`:cmd/str1/str2/options`)

Tags: functions, ex-command

A `g` command can find the lines globally and then apply actions, like the following would find lines that contain `foo` and delete those lines: `:g/foo/d`

An `s` command is more well-known for its substitution power: `:s/foo/bar/` would substitute the first `foo` of the current line with `bar`.

I wonder if it is possible to create my own excmd which takes this form `:<excmd>/<1st param>/<2nd param>/<options>`, which, in turn calls a function like `MyFunc( param1, param2, options )`.

Having this syntactic sugar would greatly help since the function should deal with quotes, whitespaces and other special characters (like `!`, `%`) a lot, and using `/` as the delimiter would greatly avoid much escaping problems.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. You'll just need to parse the parameter you receive.

Use the first char as delimiter, and `split()` the string with this delimiter. Of course, if you wish to support stuff like `:Whatever/st\/uff/other`, it'll be a little bit more complex.

I remember to have given a few answers on SO/vi.SE that implement such command: [Here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/search-and-replace-but-ignore-text-in-quotes), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665318/vim-equivalent-of-the-tr-command/25665554#25665554).

For instance, in [lh-style](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-style/blob/master/plugin/lh-style.vim#L77) I have the following:

```
command! -nargs=1 -range -complete=custom,s:CompleteConvertNames
      \ ConvertNames <line1>,<line2>call s:ConvertNames(<f-args>)

" Function: s:ConvertNames(repl_arg) {{{3
" Syntax: ConvertNames/{regex}/{convertion_type}
function! s:ConvertNames(repl_arg) range abort
  let sep = a:repl_arg[0]
  let fields = split(a:repl_arg, sep)
  if len(fields) != 2 && len(fields) != 3
    throw ":NameConvert/{regex}/{convertion_type}/[{opt}] expects exactly two or three parameters"
  endif
  let convertion_type = fields[1]
  let i = lh#list#find_if(s:k_convertions, 'v:1_[0]=='.string(convertion_type))
  if i == -1
    throw "convertion (".convertion_type.") not found"
  endif
  " build the action to execute
  let ConvertFunc = function(s:k_convertions[i][1])
  let action = '\=(ConvertFunc(submatch(0)))'
  let cmd = a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 's'
        \. sep . fields[0]
        \. sep . action
        \. sep.(len(fields)>=3 ? fields[2] : '')
  " echomsg cmd
  exe cmd
endfunction
```

EDIT: Here is another (untested) example:

```
command! -nargs=1 
      \ Hello call s:Hello(<f-args>)

function! s:ConvertNames(repl_arg) range abort
  let sep = a:repl_arg[0]
  let fields = split(a:repl_arg, sep)
  let cmd = 'echo "Hello".'.string(join(fields, ',')))
  exe cmd
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry I don't understand how it works.. May I have an example of using `:Hello/world/name` which does `:echo 'Hello world, name!'`?

Comment: That && in the if seems like a bug

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble. I had to read it several times, but it doesn't seems so. It's equivalent to `!( (len == 3) || (len == 2) )` which seems to be exactly what I wanted to test. Anyway, thank you for checking the code :)

Comment: I misread; it is correct, if still difficult to parse. No matter.